# Php return json with complex structure

Tags: php, json, rest

I'm a new PHP developer. I'm developing rest server using PHP. Now I need to return to my client json with structure like this:

```
{
"id":"45",
"login":"OlegRy",
"image":"no_avatar.png",
"fon":"",
"messages":[
    {
        id:1,
        text:hi
    },
    {
        id:2,
        text:how are u?
    }
],"subs_login":[]}
```

Tell me, please, way to realize it

Comment: tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create that data structure using array() in PHP

```
$out = array("id" => "45",
  "login" => "OlegRy",
  "image" => "no_avatar.png",
  "fon" => "",
  "messages" => array(
    array("id" => 1,
          "text" => "hi"
      ),
    array(
      "id" => 2,
      "t)xt" => "how are u?"
      )
  ),
  "subs_login" => array()
  );
echo json_encode($out);
```

Additional notes:

If you are using output buffering I'd suggest using `ob_clean();` before you echo the json.

Depending on what data format you want front end you may like to use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK with json_encode() to keep integers from being converted to strings.

```
echo json_encode($out, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

You may also want to `exit();` immediately after you echo the json to prevent any further output depending on your PHP architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This simple code :

```
$data = array(
    'id' => 45,
    'login' => 'OlegRy',
    'image' => 'no_avatar.png',
    'fon' => '',
    'messages' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'text' => 'hi',
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 2,
            'text' => 'how are u?',
        ),
    ),
    'subs_login' => array(
        // I dont't know what to put here...
    ),
);
echo json_encode($data);
```